# Installing an ancient Linux version (Ubuntu 5.04) on Virtualbox shows hard disk not found error

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and trying to install an old (ancient!) version of Ubuntu (5.04) using Virtualbox. However, when installing it inside Virtualbox, it shows the error: `No partitionable media were found`.

I can confirm that the virtual hard-disk is definitely attached. I use the same process to install newer Ubuntu releases, however this old release is unable to identify the virtual hard disk. Any ideas how I could resolve this issue and use this ancient release?

Moreover, is there any other way I can try out this other release? I need it to be able to run some old code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the hard drive as SATA?  I have a feeling that Ubuntu 5.04 might have very little support for SATA controllers.  Try creating an IDE controller and hard drive in VirtualBox and run the installer.

Comment: You may be right. However, I can not create another IDE controller. It's being used by the iso disk. Don't know why it isn't allowing me to create another IDE controller. For now, I am using the live disk. It is performing well for me. Will try installing it later by tweaking around the controllers.

Comment: Or possibly try SCSI.   https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html

Comment: Trying SCSI didn't work too. However, I was able to add the virtual hard-disk to the same IDE controller as the virtual iso disk. And now, I am able to install Ubuntu! Thanks a lot. This resolved the issue. You may want to update the answer a little, however.